# how to convert iso datetime to date in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, datetime-conversion

I m failing to convert an `ISO` `DateTime` format value to date value only. I tried `Parse`, `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` and all failed and keep giving me the same value output (`1984-04-26T00:00:00`).

I have referred to many [references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and other SO questions but none helped

I am using a DTO and this is the property,

```
public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
```

I am running a `for` loop to join data from my `LINQ` queries and I am trying to do my conversion as follows,

```
for (int i = 0; i < PatientInfo.Count; i++)
{
    PatientInfo[i].Dob =
    DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString()));
    PatientInfo[i].PartnerData = PartnerInfo.Where(a => a.FileId == PartnerInfo[i].FileId).ToList();
}
```

**What am I missing here?**

the following is the `API controller` code,

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPatReg([FromRoute] long id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var PatientInfo = await _context.PatReg
        .Where(a => a.FileId == id)
        .Select(b => new PatRegDto
        {
            Action = "Get",
            FileId = b.FileId,
            FName = b.FName,
            MName = b.MName,
            LName = b.LName,
            Dob = b.Dob
        }).ToListAsync();
    var PartnerInfo = await _context.PatPar
        .Where(s => s.FileId == id)
        .Select(m => new PatParDto
        {
            RecId = m.RecId,
            FileId = m.FileId,
            ParFileId = m.ParFileId,
            SDate = m.SDate,
            EDate = m.EDate,
        }).ToListAsync();

    for (int i = 0; i < PartnerInfo.Count; i++)

    {
        PartnerInfo[i].FullName = _context.PatReg.Where(a => a.FileId == PartnerInfo[i].ParFileId)
                               .Select(t => new { t.fullname })
                               .Single().fullname;
        PartnerInfo[i].dob = _context.PatReg.Where(a => a.FileId == PartnerInfo[i].ParFileId)
                               .Select(t => new { t.Dob })
                               .Single().Dob;

        PartnerInfo[i].Action = "Get";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PatientInfo.Count; i++)

    {
        PatientInfo[i].Dob =
        DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString()));

        PatientInfo[i].PartnerData = PartnerInfo.Where(a => a.FileId == PartnerInfo[i].FileId).ToList();
    }

    if (PatientInfo == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var DataRes = new
    {
        sdata = PatientInfo
    };

    return Ok(DataRes);
}
```

**Update**
My DTOs are

```
    public class PatRegDto

    {
        public string Action { get; set; }
        private Int64 _FileId;
        public Int64 FileId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._FileId;
            }
            set
            {
                this._FileId = value;
            }
        }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string MName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string fullname
        {
            get { return FName + " " + MName + " " + LName; }
        }
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
        public List<PatParDto> PartnerData { get; set; }
    }
    public class PatParDto

    {
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public long RecId { get; set; }
        public long FileId { get; set; }
        public long ParFileId { get; set; }
        public DateTime SDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: A `DateTime` is basically just an `Int64` counting the ticks since `0000-01-01 00:00:00.000000` (and a flag if it's "local" or UTC or unknown iirc). So you will never have just a "date", you will always also have "time" information, down to ticks. It's by convention that `dateTimeValue.Date` returns a `DateTime` value, where hours, minutes, seconds and below are all set to zero.

Comment: I think `DateTime` struct doesn't have specific formatting (only local time/UTC flag), it's the string formatting which determines date format (UTC, American time, etc.). And what the point you're re-assigning `DateTime` like this: `PatientInfo[i].Dob = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString()));`?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I m trying to replace the old value with the new format

Comment: @JSON Then you should represent the new format as `string` property on the output instead of `DateTime`. `DateTime` itself is a `struct` which doesn't have any date format, only some integer date/time properties & a flag to determine local/UTC time.

Comment: `PatientInfo[i].Dob = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString()));` -- doesn't make sense and definitely doesn't "change the format of the DateTime". A `DateTime` **does not have** a format. You *give* it the format you want, when you call `ToString` (either explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, the string value won't match `PatientInfo[i].Dob` which is of a `DateTime`, No?

Comment: @Corak, I tried  `DateTime.ParseExact(PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY"), "MM/dd/YYYY", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);` but did not work neither

Comment: then either make dob a string value, or whenever you display dob you format it to the format of your choosing.

Comment: Please do not use  `PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString())` because it will be serialized to string using your current culture settings. Depends on your OS language settings you will have different string.

Beside that DateTime contains [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property that returns date ;)

Comment: @JSON I think you need to strip out `DateTime.Parse` or any `DateTime` conversion methods and use another string property to hold the formatting: `public string DobFormat { get; set; }` then `PatientInfo[i].DobFormat = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString())`.

Comment: @JSON - yes, of course. That's basically like doing `int i = int.Parse(1.ToString("000"));` -- it won't change the "format" of `1`, because `1` *does not have* a format. -- just like any `DateTime` value does not have a format.

Comment: @JSON you were (or still are) very confused about what `DateTime` is. It merely stores the ticks, hours, days, etc. It does not contain a format. It only shows a format when it converted into a `string`. Of course when it is converted to a `string`, you'll need to be careful about any culture information that may or may not be needed in your application. But it is only then, at turning `DateTime` into a `string` can you give it a format.

Comment: side note, you have an if statement that won't be reached, `if(PatientInfo==null)`, if it was null whenever you use `PatientInfo` before this statement you will get a null error

Comment: @Dennis.Verweij - you're right, and `DateTime` doesn't even "store" hours, dates, etc.; `DateTime` is just one number (again, basically a `(U)Int64`) and everything else is (*very* quickly) calculated on demand from that.

Comment: @Corak I thought as much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use `PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString())` because it will be serialized to string using your current culture settings. Depends on your OS language settings you will have different string. Beside that `DateTime` contains [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property that returns date ;)

Comment: could you please share your thoughts with the codes above?

Answer (score 0):

So is this the only solution?
I add a `public string DobFormat { get; set; }` to the `PatRegDto` `DTO` and then,

```
for (int i = 0; i < PatientInfo.Count; i++)

            {
                PatientInfo[i].DobFormat = PatientInfo[i].Dob.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                PatientInfo[i].PartnerData = PartnerInfo.Where(a => a.FileId == PartnerInfo[i].FileId).ToList();

            }
```

Comment: This just depends what you want to store - a `string` or a `DateTime`. It's up to you really.

Comment: I think I will keep it untouched and handle my resulting object on the client side by formatting these dates using moment-js

Comment: You know you don't format dates, right? You format strings. The strings can then be parsed as dates.

Comment: @Enigmativity, yes sure. my problem is that I used to do it in a complete different way. I used to use SQL SPs and in those I could format my dates the way I want it (which basically output as a string) I just missed it here but thank you I meant formatting the string output

Comment: I don't understand why you think SPs could format the dates better than .NET. Basically they do exactly the same thing - with .NET probably being far more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Another Answer per all the valuable comments above,

public class PatRegDto

```
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    private Int64 _FileId;
    public Int64 FileId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._FileId;
        }
        set
        {
            this._FileId = value;
        }
    }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string MName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string fullname
    {
        get { return FName + " " + MName + " " + LName; }
    }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
    public List<PatParDto> PartnerData { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
var PatientInfo = await _context.PatReg
        .Where(a => a.FileId == id)
        .Select(b => new PatRegDto
        {
            Action = "Get",
            FileId = b.FileId,
            FName = b.FName,
            MName = b.MName,
            LName = b.LName,
            Dob = (b.Dob).ToString("dd/M/yyyy"),
        }).ToListAsync();
```